# Counting sequence by group

Tags: sas

Lets say I ahve a dataset as follows:

```
ID  Cat 
101 G
101 G
101 F
101 G
102 F
102 F
102 G
102 F
102 F
```

i want to create a variable for sequence by group variable ID,Cat(notsorted)

a count can be this way

```
data X1; set have; by ID, cat notsorted;
if first.cat then count=1; else count+1;run;


ID  Cat count
101 G    1
101 G    2
101 F    1
101 G    1
102 F    1
102 F    2
102 G    1
102 F    1
102 F    1
```

however what I am looking for is.

```
ID  Cat Seq
101 G    1
101 G    1
101 F    2
101 G    3
102 F    1
102 F    1
102 G    2
102 F    3
102 F    3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use

```
seq+first.cat;
```

So every time you start a new CAT value the SEQ will increment by one.

To reset for each ID add:

```
if first.id then seq=1;
```